# General Lebesgue Integral Problem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am stumped on trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let f be a measurable function in E which can be expressed as $$ f = g +h$$ Where g is finite and integrable over E and h is nonnegative on E.  Define  $$ \int_{E}^{} f=\int_{E}^{} g+\int_{E}^{} h $$    Show that this is properly defined in the sense that it is independent of the particular choice of finite integrable function g and nonnegative function h whose sum is f.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm not sure how to begin the proof.  I understand the definitions.  The integral of g is finite (since it is integrable) and the integral of h is properly defined since it is nonnegative.

Comment: Suppose that $f=g_0+h_0=g_1+h_1$. If $h_0$ or $h_1$ have infinite (positive) integral, then so does the other, and the claim holds as $+\infty=+\infty$, so we may assume that $h_0$ and $h_1$ both have finite integrals.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then since g has finite integral then the integral is properly defined? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Im trying this problem now and I feel like there is nothing to prove here. If $g_0+h_0=g_1+h_1$ where $h_0$ and $h_1$ are integrable then doesnt monotonicity and linearity imply $\int_E g_0+ \int_E h_0=\int_E g_1+ \int_E h_1$? or is there more to it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Really, I do not know what to prove here.